# How to call class and inner class in each loop using jquery

Tags: html, jquery

I'm not sure this is a good question or not but is this logic possible or not? that is, I have html code of two same `div` class (graphsdetails) name and each `div` class name has `img and b` tag attributes and when the page is loaded I should fill (`ex: img and b tag`) using jQuery .each loop

This is my html code:

```
<div id="strategydiploy_0" class="tab-pane fade show active">
    <div class="graphsdetails">
        <a>
            <span>
                <em>
                    <img alt="" title="" src="a" class="img-responsive center-block sbimage">
                </em><i class=""
                    data-placement="left" data-bs-original-title=""></i>
                <b class="sbname"></b>
            </span><i class="autodeploychkbox"></i>
        </a><a>
            <span>
                <em>
                    <img alt=""
                        title=""
                        src="a"
                        class="img-responsive center-block sbimage">
                </em><i class=""
                    data-placement="left" data-original-title=""></i>
                <b class="sbname"></b>
            </span><i class="autodeploychkbox"></i>
        </a><a>
            <span>
                <em>
                    <img alt=""
                        title=""
                        src="a"
                        class="img-responsive center-block sbimage">
                </em><i class=""
                    data-placement="left" data-original-title=""></i>
                <b class="sbname"></b>
            </span><i class="autodeploychkbox"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="strategydiploy_1" class="tab-pane fade ">
    <div class="graphsdetails"><a>
            <span>
                <em>
                    <img alt=""
                        title=""
                        src="a"
                        class="img-responsive center-block sbimage">
                </em><i class=""
                    data-placement="left" data-original-title=""></i>
                <b class="sbname"></b>
            </span><i class="autodeploychkbox"></i>
        </a><a>
            <span>
                <em>
                    <img alt=""
                        title=""
                        src="a"
                        class="img-responsive center-block sbimage">
                </em><i class=""
                    data-placement="left" data-original-title=""></i>
                <b class="sbname"></b>
            </span><i class="autodeploychkbox"></i>
        </a><a>
            <span>
                <em>
                    <img alt=""
                        title=""
                        src="a"
                        class="img-responsive center-block sbimage">
                </em><i class=""
                    data-placement="left" data-original-title=""></i>
                <b class="sbname"></b>
            </span><i class="autodeploychkbox"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

my requirement is when the page is loaded the `img src ="" and b tag` data should fill automatically

ex:

1.

```
<img alt="" title="" src="https://somelink.com/test.png" class="img-responsive center-block sbimage"> <b class="sbname">some text</b>
```

2. 

```
<img alt="" title="" src="https://somelink.com/test_1.png" class="img-responsive center-block sbimage"><b class="sbname">some image text</b>`
```

like above example all the `img and b` tags data should fill

To achieve this I have written logic like below

```
function LoadSBImages() {


    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        data: "{}",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
        url:"page.aspx/GetSBImages",

        success: function (result) {
            var imgcount = 0;
//sbimage image class looping 
            $(".sbimage").each(function () {

                //alert(imgcount);

                $(this).attr('src', result.d[imgcount].ImgaeURL); // able to filling the image src 
                $('.sbname').html(result.d[imgcount].StragyName); // b tag attribute data filling (but filling the last name to all the b tag)

                imgcount++;

            });

        },

        error: function ajaxError (result) {

            alert(result.status + ' : ' + result.statusText);
        }

    });

}
```

I have tried myself some example like this below but not working

```
$(".graphsdetails > .sbimage >.sbname").each(function () {

                $('.sbimage').attr('src', result.d[imgcount].ImgaeURL);
                $('.sbname').html(result.d[imgcount].StragyName);

})
```

Suggest me how to achieve this

I'm new to jQuery logics

Comment: loop through the parent class only, inside .each(), select the child of the particular parent class => $(this) individualy, and apply the logic

Comment: Define “not working”. Tangential, but are the properties really named `ImgaeURL` and `StragyName`?!

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes I have given the same property name

Comment: @YashSoni can you please suggest me with the sample code that will help me a lot because I'm new to this logic (jQuery).

Comment: @Kumar DaveNewton is letting you know they are misspelt.  eg ImageURL / StrategyName

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/each/ has an `index` parameter, so you don't need `imgcount`

Comment: Given your layout, and *assuming* the img is set correctly, change `$('.sbname').html..` to `$(this).closest("a").find(".sbname").html(...`   you'll find it easier if you work down though, eg `$(".graphsdetails > a").each(...` then `$(this).find(".sbimage").attr("src"..` and `$(this).find(".sbname).html(...`

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do this, if the logic wants to loop through each parent and then update child `img` and `b` tags, then go for this

```
   // loop through parent div
  $('.graphsdetails').each(function (i, obj) {

    // since there are multiple img tags, loop through all to update src
    $(this).find('img.sbimage').each(function () {
      $(this).attr('src','YOUR NEW IMG SOURCE');
    });

    // same logic for b tag
    $(this).find('b.sbname').each(function () {
        $(this).html('YOUR HTML HERE');
      });
  });
```

Another way is, independent of parent `div`

```
  $('img.sbimage').each(function () {
      $(this).attr('src','YOUR NEW IMG SOURCE');
    });

  $('b.sbname').each(function () {
        $(this).html('YOUR HTML HERE');
  });
```

Only looping through `img` and `b` tags directly and updating the source and html. See what suits according to your business and pick one ;)